# How is the server responsive to the client in the code below?

Tags: java, multithreading

The code below creates a server..

```
package practice;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SimpleChatServer 
{
    private ArrayList clientOutputStreams;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SimpleChatServer serve = new SimpleChatServer();
        serve.go();
    }
    public void go()
    {
        clientOutputStreams = new ArrayList();


        try
        {
            ServerSocket sock = new ServerSocket(5001);
            while(true)
            {
                Socket clientSocket = sock.accept();
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                clientOutputStreams.add(writer);

                Thread t = new Thread(new ClientHandler(clientSocket));
                t.start();
                System.out.println("New client connected");
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error in the go function");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class ClientHandler implements Runnable
    {
        private Socket client;
        BufferedReader reader;
        public ClientHandler(Socket socket)
        {
            try
            {
            client = socket;
            InputStreamReader instream = new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream());
            reader = new BufferedReader(instream);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
            String inMessage = null;
            while((inMessage = reader.readLine())!=null)
            {
                tellEveryone(inMessage);
            }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
    }

    private void tellEveryone(String message)
    {
        Iterator it = clientOutputStreams.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            PrintWriter pen = (PrintWriter)it.next();
            pen.println(message);
            pen.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

The code that I don't understand is this..

```
while((inMessage = reader.readLine())!=null)
{
                tellEveryone(inMessage);
}
```

My doubt: If there is no message from the client side initially, wouldn't the statement inside while() evaluate to false, resulting in the thread finishing running the code it had to run. How is it able to continue to listen for messages from the same client without an infinite loop or something.

Also if you down vote my question.Please let me know why.

Comment: If you are using Java 1.5 or higher then you should use parametrized (generic) List<T> interface and ArrayList<T> implementation instead of just plain ArrayList that stores Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`inMessage = reader.readLine()` won't produce a null because it will block

1. Until it gets anything to process or
2. Socket connection is terminated.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

`client.getInputStream()` returns a blocking stream. This means the thread reading this stream is blocked until some bytes are available to be read.

So, `while((inMessage = reader.readLine())!=null)` line will wait until a message received. When the message arrived, then the reader will return it and the while block will be executed.